# Capture string between delimiters

Tags: regex, groovy

What would be the shortest solution to capture a string between two markers?

For example, let's imagine I have

> blahblahblah ---foobar-- blahblahblah

And I want to capture "foobar".

I can capture the string "---foobar--" quite easily with a regex.

But since I don't want the prefix "---" and suffix "--", I need many steps to clean up the result :

1. get position of prefix "---" (since we already captured the bloc, we know the position is 0)
2. get length of "---" (for the sake of the example, let's assume we don't know the size of the limiter, it can be "---" or "--" or "-")
3. get position of suffix "--", starting at position position_prefix+prefix_length
4. substring between position_prefix+prefix_length and position_suffix

Of course I can build myself such a function to do that if I need it, but is there already a built-in solution for that?

Something like captureWithoutDelimiters(group_regex, prefix_regex, suffix_regex) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
[\w\s]+-+(\w+)-+[\w\s]+
```

Then you can just print out what's caught by the first capture group.

Explanation:

```
[\w\s]+     // Match at lest 1 letter or white space character
-+          // Followed by at least 1 marker character
(\w+)       // Capture the word inside the markers
-+          // Followed by more marker characters
[\w\s]+     // Followed by at lest 1 letter/white space character
```

Comment: I didn't know about capture groups, seems like the ideal tool for the job!

Answer (score 1):

The **shortest** solution probably would be

```
.split("-+")[1]
```

If you require `---` as prefix and `--` as postfix and you allow `-` anywhere in text, then split solution is

```
.split("---")[1].split("--")[0]
```

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/Pq07l7).